# django allauth: remove social application

Tags: django, django-allauth

I had Facebook and Google set up as providers for signing into my website using django allauth.

I don't want to use Facebook SocialApp anymore so I deleted it via the admin console. I also removed it from my `settings.py`

I deleted Facebook SocialApp so why do I still get this error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /accounts/login/
No Facebook app configured: please add a SocialApp using the Django admin
```

Which other files need to be edited so that my django allauth configuration knows that only google needs to be used in the list of provider?

My settings.py currently looks like this:

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'multicam',
    'avatar',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'last_seen',
)

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'last_seen.middleware.LastSeenMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)
```

I would really appreciate any help on getting my allauth configuration setup correctly. Thank you.

Comment: See if you have SOCIAL_ACCOUNT_PROVIDERS configured in your settings.py with facebook in it

Comment: @e4c5 how do I access SOCIAL_ACCOUNT_PROVIDERS? I don't see it in the admin console. Is it something I need to edit via Shell or a variable within a file? I'm very new to django so I apologize for such basic questions.

Comment: **in your settings.py **

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually if you are removing one of the providers, you will land up in so many problems.

It all starts with the settings file, where you will have to delete each and avery mention of facebook app. After that you will have to delete facebook from the socialapps table.

Now if any user had logged into the website with facebook, either you should delete them(unlikely) or you should modify them as their provider would still be referencing to the facebook app.

Just keep in mind that you have to analyse the database tables and delete or modify each reference of the app you are deleting.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following:

> pip uninstall django-allauth

And delete all references of django-allauth from settings.py and urls.py mentioned in the following link:

https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Look at your settings.py for all django-allauth related settings.
2. Look at your urls.py for django-allauth related paths.
3. You will need to update your tables.
4. Finally uninstall django-allauth and other dependent apps it brought something similar to :

```
pip uninstall certifi cffi chardet cryptography django-allauth defusedxml idna oauthlib pycparser PyJWT python3-openid requests requests-oauthlib six
```